# Azure file share integration with AAD DS

Tags: azure

since this week I am facing with azure file share map issue.
I have a VM AAD DS domain joined and it's working fine.
I am trying to map am Azure file share but I get credential prompt.
I expect to login with integrated authentication.
I followed all the steps 3 times but with same results.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-auth-active-directory-domain-service-enable#mount-a-file-share-from-a-domain-joined-vm

Last week everything was working fine.
Does someone faced with my same issue?

Thanks

Comment: can you give us some example code of are you doing? it will. help us to simulate this error in our machine

Comment: I am NOT BE ABLE to map the Azure file share using the integrated authentication, I am keeping to to get same prompt (username and password) like I have no permission on the share, instead I've assigned.

Comment: I have escalated to microsoft opening an SR. They fixed!